# Sending HTML email intents without having <img>'s removed?

Tags: android, html, image, email, android-intent

*Note: I know there are a lot of similar questions on SO.  However, I am not trying to inline these images, I just want the html to stay as is.*

It seems like the normal way to send html emails through an intent is to use Html.fromHtml(String)

For example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/html");
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(htmlString));
startActivity(intent);
```

However, as it states in its documentation, it replaces all  tags with a special character for use with an ImageGetter.

I do not want to inline and attach these images.  I just want the img tags to stay as is in the html.  I do not need to attach the images.

For example, I want:
`<img src="http://www.somedomain.com/somewebsite/someimage.jpg" />` to stay that way.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Standard Compliant eMail Clients will always strip img tags, until the user grants permission otherwise.

Images in emails can identify your computer on the server from they are being requested from, thus its a security measure and will stay like that until a new, better system is created.

Comment: re email clients stripping img tags: not fully true, it's not a standards compliance thing, it's a security/privacy thing.  and also img tags that reference attached images rather than urls are not stripped by most email clients

Comment: I'm not sure this is answers the question. The OP is trying to *send* image tags in the email, and that's not working; getting them displayed on the client side (working about clients that strip img tags) is another problem entirely.

Comment: How could i grant this permission?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't just want the following?

`intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, htmlString);`

Seems odd to attach a Spanned to the intent rather than just handing over the HTML itself.

Comment: I tried that but email applications like Gmail then show the html code like raw text.  It doesn't seem to render it.

Comment: No, what the OP did is the correct method. If the text passed is a string, it's interpreted as plain text, even with HTML tags.